# Using callbacks with sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Okay so below is a snippet of my code where I have cut many unnecessary things and unrelated but I have left the part dealing with the question.

I am using callbacks while calling the functions needed to run the necessary queries. Since I have many queries like these below, I was wondering if thats the right way to ensure the wanted order for the queries to be executed. I know I could remove the functions and simply put them inside a serialize but its really ugly to repeat the same code so I put them in functions, to put it more clear here is my question.

Question: If I have many queries inside functions the correct way to ensure the get executed in the wanted order is with callbacks as I have done?, even in cases where you dont want to return anything e.g (when updating a row/table in the DB)

```
get_data(pel, function(results){
    var cntl = results;
    get_user(pel, function(results_from_user){
        update_data(0, 0, function(cb_result){

                //do some stuff
        });
    });
});

function get_data(dt, callback)
{
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM my_table`, function(error, row) {
        var data_to_return = [..];
        return callback(data_to_return);
    });
}

function update_data(vdr,dwe,callback)
{ 
    db.run(`UPDATE my_table SET val1='${..}', val2 = '${..}'`);
    //..
    return callback("updated");
}

function get_user(ms, callback)
{
    db.get(`SELECT id FROM my_table_2 WHERE id=${..};`, function(error, row) {
        if(row == undefined) db.run(`INSERT INTO my_table_2 (id) VALUES (?)`,[0]);
        //..
        var id_to_return = [..];
        return callback(id_to_return);
    });
}
```

perhaps I should add my code is working as expected, I am just making sure I am not using a weird way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can ensure you that you have made a typical solution. in fact callback are used to wait for the response before moving on to the next statement.Goog job

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait a bit more if you dont mind for a few more answers, in case they pop up and say anything interesting, otherwise I'll approve yours.

Comment: Oh yeah one thing I was wondering about, if I dont want to return anything with my callback - but I want to wait for the function to finish, should I return true or something and just never use it?

Comment: yes you could retrun anything you want and never user it